# Bonding in boron icosahedra

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, valence-bond-theory, boron-family

How do boron atoms make five bonds with other boron atoms even if the electron configuration of unbound boron atoms is [He]2s²2p¹, i.e. there is an insufficient number of outer electrons? Are the inner electrons ([He]) involved in binding?

[image]

$\ce{B12H12^2-}$, source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dodecaborate(12)-dianion-from-xtal-3D-bs-17.png

Comment: Even though you've completely rewritten the question, it's still cryptic. Boron-12 refers to an isotope $\ce{^{12}B},$ but I think you are asking about the $\ce{B12}$ icosahedra of either a standalone cluster, or a certain allotrope (which one?). Also, what "*stable core*" are you asking about? I suspect this could be a duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32319, but I'm not sure I fully understand the question.

Comment: Be aware that laconic, not elaborated questions are usually closed on the StackExchange network.    [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).
Describe the question well, search, think, refer and summarize.  Well elaborated questions have higher probability to  receive acceptable answers. 
Lack of explicit, a priori effort may cause missing existing answers, question misinterpretation, needed clarification and  difficult estimation of the OP knowledge .

Comment: The short answer is that a bond can cover multiple linkages, not just a single pair of atoms; therefore an atom can be joined to more neighbors than the number of bonds it forms. When you learn about molecular orbitals you can see how this happens.

Comment: @andselisk I am talking of dodecahedron structure of boron-12 and not of isotopes .

Comment: @Get_Maths You've probably misread my comment. "Boron-12" *is* a notation for isotope that is equivalent to $\ce{^{12}B}.$ In the context of recent edit, you should refer to your composition as to dodecaborate, not boron-12 since the latter causes confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Boron makes not five but six bonds in compounds such as dodecaborate or boron carbide. Boron carbide is a semiconductor, so it has aspects of a metal and a non-metal. For actual metals such a elemental sodium, you have to explain twelve nearest neighbors with only 1 outer electron, so there is no way to describe it with covalent bonds. For boron carbide, you can get away with invoking 3 center 2 electron bonds, but it is not clear if there is much insight to be gained.

Roald Hoffmann wrote a detailed account of bonding in boron carbide [here](http://www.roaldhoffmann.com/sites/all/files/523.pdf). Even if all you get out of it is that boron makes beautiful intricate structures, and 2 electron bonds do not do justice to all compounds known, it is worthwhile taking a look.

[image]

I don't think any of the bonding models make use of the inner electrons.

Comment: But if boron's maximum covalency is 4 , then how can it make 6 bonds

Comment: Call it advanced inorganic chemistry. Either you need less than 2 electrons per bond, or a bond connects more than two atoms. The existence and structure of the boron icosahedra is well supported by experiment. If your bonding model cannot explain it, you need a more sophisticated bonding model.